# IntelliJ: wrap javadoc text but not markup

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

I'm trying to format the following Javadoc, but I can't figure out how.

Example input:

```
/**
 * Headline.
 * <p>
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 * consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 * <p>
 * A list:
 * <ul>
 * <li>The description above should be wrapped at the right margin, and broken lines should be joined.</li>
 * <li>A line starting or ending in a tag should not be joined.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author Mark Jeronimus
 */
```

When I press 'format' I want to see this:

```
/**
 * Headline.
 * <p>
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
 * ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 * <p>
 * A list:
 * <ul>
 * <li>The description above should be wrapped at the right margin, and broken lines should
 * be joined.</li>
 * <li>A line starting or ending in a tag should not be joined.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author Mark Jeronimus
 */
```

Eclipse and NetBeans do this easily. IntelliJ, if I configure it to wrap text (which I require) it also joins tags except `<p>`. (Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> JavaDoc -> Other -> Wrap at right margin). It looks like this:

```
/**
 * Headline.
 * <p>
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
 * ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 * <p>
 * A list: <ul> <li>The description above should be wrapped at the right margin, and broken
 * lines should be joined.</li> <li>A line starting or ending in a tag should not be joined.
 * </li> </ul>
 *
 * @author Mark Jeronimus
 */
```

I tried changing the other settings in the hope some of them interfere with each other, to no avail.

What I don't want is to use the Eclipse Formatter plugin. I feel IntelliJ should be able to handle such basic behavior itself, or how is anyone supposed to format their Javadoc in a normal way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **Preferences**
2. Select **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Java**
3. Open the **JavaDoc** tab
4. Set the following options

   > Blank lines
   >    ✓ After description *This is a javadoc standard, other blank lines are optional*
   >   Other
   >    ✓ Wrap at right margin
   >    ✓ Enable leading asterisks
   >    ✓ Generate "<p>" on empty lines
   >    ✓ Keep empty lines
   >    ✗ Preserve line feeds
5. Click **OK**
6. Then just use **Code** > **Reformat Code**

Of course you can tweak the preferences according to your own...preference. This setup will realign the text to fit in the margins but you will have to put the <ul> tag on a new line before formatting.

Comment: This has been fixed in IDEA a long time ago. I already had those settings like that. But thanks anyway.